# How to "test" if a variable greater than another variable in DOS?

Tags: batch-file

I have written this code in DOS but it not working, it only says less even if its greater. Here is the code

```
:new
cls
set /a ran=(%random% %%10000)+1
GOTO test

:test

set /P nmb=number:
if "%nmb%" LSS "%ran%" GOTO less
if "%nmb%" GTR "%ran%" GOTO greater
if "%nmb%"=="%ran%" GOTO equal

:less
echo less
GOTO test

:greater
echo greater
GOTO test

:equal
echo equal
GOTO new
```

Comment: This code won't work in `DOS`. There is no `set /a` and no comparators for `if` except `==`.  Do you work on the Windows Command Line (`cmd`)  instead?

Comment: When comparing numbers, don't force to string mode. `10` is less than `2` in string mode. Remove the quotes.

Comment: DOS and cmd are very different things [Are the Command Prompt and MS-DOS the same thing?](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)